How can I protect a 8x8 post from 8" of concrete?
I am pouring a slab but there is a 8x8 post in the way how can I protect at least 8" of post from the concrete eating the post?

Quite a few posts, including fence posts are placed in concrete.  The main problem is pulling up the concrete if the post breaks/rots above ground.  I am assuming wood posts.

Cut a 12" ("more than 8" depth" so not a critical dimension) section of roofing felt, wrap it around the post. If you don't have roofing felt, rather than buying a whole roll for a tiny bit, you can use flashing tape, sill seal, vapor barrier plastic, etc...
